# Resharper Live Template Macro that changes variable name upon exit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, macros, resharper, live-templates

I would like to create a Resharper Live Template that changes all spaces to underscores ind my "fact" Live template variable $testname$:

```
<Fact()> _
Public Sub $testnames$()
    ' Arrange
    $END$

    ' Act

    ' Assert

End Sub
```

I have this:

```
    [Macro("applyRegex", ShortDescription = "Run on {#0:variable}", LongDescription = "")]
    class ApplyRegexMacro : IMacro
    {
        public string EvaluateQuickResult(IHotspotContext context, IList<string> arguments)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(arguments[0], " ", "_", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        public HotspotItems GetLookupItems(IHotspotContext context, IList<string> arguments)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public string GetPlaceholder()
        {
            return "placeholder";
        }

        public bool HandleExpansion(IHotspotContext context, IList<string> arguments)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public ParameterInfo[] Parameters
        {
            get
            {
                return new[] { new ParameterInfo(ParameterType.String), new ParameterInfo(ParameterType.String), new ParameterInfo(ParameterType.VariableReference) };           
            }
        }
    }
```

But this only runs when i press tab. I want the macro to run after I tab out of $testname$.

I want to be able to just write the test name in a single line of text with spaces, and then the Macro turns all the spaces into underscores.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution after all? Did you associate your macro with a given variable?

Comment: Have the same problem. It seems like its a built-in macro now, I just can't figure out how to invoke it after I have typed the name for the variable. Have you solved the problem, if so, how ?